# Which of the following must be true?

Tags: functions, derivatives

[image: pic]

Please solve this task or give me some hints on how to approach it.

Comment: Hint: what is the derivative of $f(x)$?

Comment: Take the derivative of $f(x)$ wrt $x$ and substitute $h^\prime (x)$, you will get $f^\prime  (x)= 0 \implies f(x)$ is constant.

Comment: @anubhav after derivation I got f′(x) = f(x)(g(x) - g'(x), but how did you get 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using product rule,

$f^\prime (x) = e^{g(x)}h^\prime(x) + h(x)(e^{g(x)})^\prime$

Using Chain rule on second term,
$f^\prime (x) = e^{g(x)}h^\prime(x) + h(x)e^{g(x)}g^\prime(x)$

Now, substitute $h^\prime (x)$, you will get

$f^\prime (x) = -e^{g(x)}g ^\prime(x)h(x) + h(x)e^{g(x)}g^\prime(x) = 0$
$\implies f = constant $

Comment: ooooh thanks a lot, I found an error in my calculations